# Run function inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I run this code:

```
var alts = {};
$('.grid ul').find('.lista-produtos:visible').each(function(){
  var classes2 = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < classes2.length; i++) {
      var matches2 = /^tipo\-(.+)/.exec(classes2[i]);
      if (matches2 != null) {
        var produto2 = matches2[1];
      }
    }
  if(!alts[classes2]){
      alts[classes2] = true;
      $('ul.filters').append('<li class="filter-produto">'+ produto2 +'</li>');   
  }  
});
```

as a function, like this:

```
function tipoProduto(){ 

var alts = {};
$('.grid ul').find('.lista-produtos:visible').each(function(){
      var classes2 = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
      for (var i = 0; i < classes2.length; i++) {
          var matches2 = /^tipo\-(.+)/.exec(classes2[i]);
          if (matches2 != null) {
            var produto2 = matches2[1];
          }
        }
      if(!alts[classes2]){
          alts[classes2] = true;
          $('ul.filters').append('<li class="filter-produto">'+ produto2 +'</li>');   
      }  
});
}
```

and call it here:

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function(){
    var classes1 = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < classes1.length; i++) {
      var matches1 = /^ctrl\-(.+)/.exec(classes1[i]);
      if (matches1 != null) {
        var marca1 = matches1[1];
      }
    }

    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.list-group-item').not(this).removeClass("active");

    if ($('.todos-produtos').hasClass("active")) {
    $('.lista-produtos').hide();
    $('.' + marca1).show();
    }
    else {
    var produto1 = $('li.filter-produto.active').text();
    $('.lista-produtos').not('.' + marca1 + '.tipo-' + produto1).hide();
    $('.' + marca1 + '.tipo-' + produto1).show()
    }

tiposProduto(); // CALLING IT HERE //

});
});
```

then this code below doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$('.filter-produto').click(function() {
    var classes3 = $('.list-group-item.active').attr('class').split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < classes3.length; i++) {
      var matches3 = /^ctrl\-(.+)/.exec(classes3[i]);
      if (matches3 != null) {
        var marca2 = matches3[1];
      }
    }

    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.filter-produto').not(this).removeClass("active");

    if ($(this).hasClass("todos-produtos")) {
    $('.' + marca2).show();
    }
    else {
    var produto3 = $(this).text();
    $(".lista-produtos").not('.tipo-' + produto3).hide();
    $('.' + marca2 + '.tipo-' + produto3).show();
    }
});
});
```

but if I change the 1st code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var alts = {};
    $('.grid ul').find('.lista-produtos:visible').each(function(){
      var classes2 = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
      for (var i = 0; i < classes2.length; i++) {
          var matches2 = /^tipo\-(.+)/.exec(classes2[i]);
          if (matches2 != null) {
            var produto2 = matches2[1];
          }
        }
      if(!alts[classes2]){
          alts[classes2] = true;
          $('ul.filters').append('<li class="filter-produto">'+ produto2 +'</li>');   
      }  
    });

});
```

then the 4th code works again.

The problem is I need the code above as a function, like I showed on the 2nd and 3rd examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Please make the test case much simpler. Eliminate all the code that doesn't directly relate to the problem.

Comment: In code 4, call the function from code 2 first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the few replies. I found out the problem.

Appended objects weren't being recognized by the functions. That's why `$('.filter-produto').click(function() {` wasn't working.